# Crontab и python скрипт

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Ubuntu 20.04 (на Raspberry)

Есть вот такой скрипт для примера:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

try:
    print("Траляля")
```

Как сервис запускается и отрабатывает без ошибок.

В оболочке bash без привязки к пользователю тоже работает запуск скрипта.
Но если попытаться от пользователя выполнить:

```
* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/GPIO/ && ./initial.py
```

выдает ошибку `initial.py: command not found`

Что можно предпринять, господа?

Comment: Может с правами не всё в порядке?

Comment: `Но если попытаться от пользователя выполнить` надеюсь, это вы привели строчку из crontab-а для пользователя ubuntu, а не попытались выполнить эту строчку как команду в оболочке?

Comment: Ёк-макарёк, а разве из командной строки я так не могу задание от пользователя в крон добавить?

Comment: В общем добавил эту запись в crontab -e и все работает... в общем тупанул

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В общем добавил эту запись в crontab -e и все работает...